# mysql_fetch_array / mysqli_fetch_array - difference in behaviour on first call (php)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm just (very belatedly I know) updating some of my code from mysql to mysqli and I've noticed what seems to be a change in behaviour in the fetch_array function.

There was no intention to obfuscate by truncating the code in the original question, but here if it helps is a fuller run down of the actual code.

**USING : MYSQL**

**THIS STEPS THROUGH EACH QUALIFY RECORD IN THE TABLE FROM FIRST TO LAST**

```
$con_head = mysql_connect($domain,$head_dbname,$head_dbpassword);
if (!$con_head)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_select_db($head_dbname, $con_head);


$src_sql = "Select * from SEQUENCES where SEQUENCE_TYPE = 'N' and REVIEWED ='N' order by SEQ_START";
$src_tb = mysql_query($src_sql, $con_head);

while ($src_rec = mysql_fetch_array($src_tb))
{
    ..... statements here have no relevance to the problem

}
```

**USING MYSQLI**

**THIS IMMEDIATELY SKIPS THE WHILE CLAUSE **

**IF THE ROW IMMEDIATELY ABOVE WHILE IS UNCOMMENTED - THIS PROCEEDS BUT STARTING FROM THE SECOND RECORD.**

```
$con_head = mysqli_connect("$domain,$head_dbname,$head_dbpassword,$head_dbname); // database name and user name are the same
if (!$con_head)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
  }
    $src_sql = "Select * from SEQUENCES where SEQUENCE_TYPE = 'N' and REVIEWED ='N' order by SEQ_START ";
$src_tb = mysqli_query($con_head, $src_sql);
//  $src_rec = mysqli_fetch_array($src_tb,MYSQLI_BOTH);
while ($src_rec = mysqli_fetch_array($src_tb,MYSQLI_BOTH))
{
    ..... statements here have no relevance to the problem

}
```

This works fine under mysql , but the equivalent under **mysqli** immediately fails the "while" test.

I've checked that otherwise the code is okay, by inserting an additional mysqli_fetch_array before commencing the loop, this works fine - although starts the processing therefore from the SECOND record.

Clearly I can rewrite my code to loop in a different way (eg having $record = mysqli_fetch_array BEFORE THE loop, having the loop testing $record and then an additional $record = mysqli_fetch_array before the end curly brace in the while loop) but I'm anxious to understand the difference in behaviour so that I don't run into any other pitfalls.

Can anyone explain?

Comment: you'll need to post what you used exactly with the `mysqli_` function. and this is wrong `mysql_query($con,$sql)`

Comment: this code you posted; doesn't hold water

Comment: "the equivalent under mysqli" — What equivalent? Show us a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem, not some code which you know does not.

Comment: please post the *real* code you run, without *any* editing.

Comment: Ok, apologies - I didn't intend to leave anything out. I've update the above with the exact code that is demonstrating the different behaviours.

Comment: also, you should explain what does "immediately fails" and also prove that this "immediate fail" is not caused by "statements that have no relevance"

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference.

Both function behave equally in every possible way.

Whatever difference you may notice is caused by your own mistake of some sort.